# How can we build and refer bom in same pom

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have one jenkins job which build parent pom. Inside parent pom I have a module BOM also. The bom itself is being referred in same parent POM like below.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.org.fgn.abs</groupId>
            <artifactId>abs-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</dependencyManagement>
```

But it is unable to find the correct version of bom. It is obvious that it won't find the bom  because it is not yet build.
I am just looking any way to do the same without having separate job for building the bom.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, good question. One option is definitely that, you could have the BOM project build first using a separate job in Jenkins and that way when you build your main Parent project it finds that dependency. I do have some projects configured that way and it should work fine.
The other option I think is you could have your BOM project as a module in another Parent project say B, and then include this Parent project in your main Parent project as a module. Honestly I haven't tried the second approach, but you could maybe this a shot.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 
< version>${project.version}< /version>

try with providing explicit version like,

< version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT< /version>

You can refer 
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom

Comment: My question is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem is to add the BOM as a module as you did, but to make sure it's the first module to be build.

```
<modules>
    <!-- Run first, not using the parent but part of the aggregator -->
    <module>bom</module>
    <!-- Module 1 using the parent -->
    <module>module1</module>
    <!-- Module 2 using the parent, depends on module 1 -->
    <module>module2</module>
</modules>
```

A simple yet excellent code example can be found at https://github.com/anliksim/maven-template-bom.

Make sure to read the remark about the versions-maven-plugin (if you are using that) and use **processAllModules**.

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.1-SNAPSHOT -DprocessAllModules=true
```